# passing data from jsp page to another using jstl

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a jsp page that shows the data from 4-5 tables.The rows in tables can vary each time and it properly shows up . I am using jstl for doing this.Now all those fields are editable. So i am not understanding how to send the data from all the tables to another jsp page .This is one of my table code..

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@BDSPIND70133047:1521/xe"
 user="BEMFH_PERSONAL"  password="pass1234"/>

 <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT * from   BFH_ERROR
 </sql:query>

 <table border="1" width="100%" id="berror">
 <br>
   <p>Table BFH_ERROR</p>
  <tr>

      <th>ERROR_ID</th>
      <th>ERROR_CODE</th>
       <th>ERROR_DESC</th>
       <th>ERROR_MSG</th>
       <th>PROGRAM_ID</th>
  </tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
  <tr>
   <TD ><INPUT type="text"   value=<c:out value="${row.ERROR_ID}"/> ></TD> 
   <TD ><INPUT type="text"   value=<c:out value="${row.ERROR_CODE}"/> ></TD> 
   <TD ><INPUT type="text"   value=<c:out value="${row.ERROR_DESC}"/> ></TD> 
   <TD ><INPUT type="text"  value=<c:out value="${row.ERROR_MSG}"/> ></TD> 
   <TD ><INPUT type="text"  value=<c:out value="${row.PROGRAM_ID}"/> ></TD> 
</tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

so i want to ask how to send the entire data from all the tables to another jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you need to POST those input field values to your server for processing.

Firstly, you need to give `name` attribute for your input fields, in-order to get their values from POST request.

```
<INPUT type="text" name="input_name"  value=<c:out value="${row.ERROR_ID}"/>
```

This has nothing to do with, JSTL. It's all about client side http [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) method.

If you are getting the values from a [servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), you will probably use the [doPost](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String value = req.getParameter("input_name");
}
```

If you are getting the values from a [jsp](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) page (which is compiled to a Servlet), do the following.

```
${request['input_name']}
```